# Implementar css en vista de laravel

Tags: html, css, laravel

Hola estoy tratando de configurar una vista pero necesito agregarle css el codigo html con boostrap que tengo en la vista es el siguiente

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->


<div class="sidenav">
         <div class="login-main-text">
            <h2>Application<br> Login Page</h2>
            <p>Login or register from here to access.</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main">
         <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="login-form">
               <form>
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label>User Name</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label>Password</label>
                     <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-black">Login</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Register</button>
               </form>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Y el código que quiero agregar lo tengo en la carpeta public con el nombre style.css, Lo que necesito es poder implementarlo, con un link no me funciono entonces como podría implementar ese código en mi vista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependiendo como esté configurado tu servidor, y si dices que el archivo css está en raíz de la carpeta public puede ser:

```
<link href="{{ asset('public/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

o puede que sea:

```
<link href="{{ asset('style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

La función `asset` genera una URL para un "asset" usando el schema actual de la petición, ya sea HTTP o HTTPS.

Si quieres definir una URL diferente, debes de cambiar la variable `ASSET_URL` en tu archivo que se encuentra en raíz de tu proyecto, llamado `.env`.